# R: match and replace string. mgsub does not work

Tags: r, string, replace, match, qdap

I have two data frames. The first data frame *lib* is a library with words in two columns. The second data frame *data1* should be transformed as follows: The strings matched in column *data1$V1* against *lib$V2* should be replaced with the string in the corresponding row in column *lib$V1*.

```
lib <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("car", "great", "huge", "car", "great", "huge"),
  v2 = c("cars", "awesome", "tall", "truck", "super", "very huge")
  )



data1 <- data.frame(
  values = c("cars", "awesome", "tall", "truck", "super", "very huge")
)
```

The final data frame data1.final should look like as follows:

```
data1.final <- data.frame(
  values = c("car", "great", "huge", "car", "great", "huge")
)
```

I tried this with the mgsub function from the **qdap** package:

```
data1$values <- mgsub(as.character(lib$V2), lib$V1, data1$values, fixed=T)
```

But nothing has changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data1.final<- data.frame(values=lib$v1[match(data1$values,lib$v2)])

> data1.final
  values
1    car
2  great
3   huge
4    car
5  great
6   huge
```

Answer (score 1):

`mgsub` is for text substitutions within strings.  What you're after is a dictionary lookup.  The `lookup` (`%l%`) from the **qdapTools** package is one of many ways to tackle this:

```
library(qdapTools)
data1$values <- data1$values %lc% lib[, 2:1]

##   values
## 1    car
## 2  great
## 3   huge
## 4    car
## 5  great
```

Note that `%lc%` (stands for lookup character) forces a character output.

To accomplish this with `mgsub` you'd have used:

```
mgsub(as.character(lib$v2), as.character(lib$v1), data1$values)
```

But this is not the best approach for this case.